# aftersave method in User and RBAC

Tags: php, database, yii2, rbac

I tried to assign a role (RBAC) to the user at registration in the SignupForm

```
public function signup()
{
    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return null;
    }

    $user = new User();
    $user->username = $this->username;
    $user->email = $this->email;
    $user->role = $this->role;
    $user->setPassword($this->password);
    $user->generateAuthKey();

    return $user->save() ? $user : null;

    $myRole = '';

    switch ($user->role) {
        case 0:
            $myRole = 'developer';
            break;
        case 1:
            $myRole = 'project_manager';
            break;
        case 2:
            $myRole = 'customer';
            break;
    }

    $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;
    $role = $auth->getRole($myRole);
    $auth->assign($role, $user->id);

    return true;

}
```

View signup

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'role')->dropDownList(
                    [
                    '0' => 'Developer',
                    '1' => 'Project Manager',
                    '2' => 'Customer'
                    ],
                    ['prompt' => 'Choose your role..']) ?>
```

It doesnt work... The table auth_assignment doesnt update, but table user updates.
If I insert this piece of code into the method afterSave in User.php

```
$myRole = '';

    switch ($user->role) {
        case 0:
            $myRole = 'developer';
            break;
        case 1:
            $myRole = 'project_manager';
            break;
        case 2:
            $myRole = 'customer';
            break;
    }

    $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;
    $role = $auth->getRole($myRole);
    $auth->assign($role, $user->id);
```

It works fine...
Who can explain, why so?

Answer (score 3):

You have a `return` in the middle of this method, so everything after `return $user->save() ? $user : null;` is a dead code.

You probably need to replace it by:

```
if (!$model->save()) {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer, try to replace your `return` with my code.

Answer (score 1):

I think it has a lot to do with this

```
return $user->save() ? $user : null;
```

you are returning the user after the save() method or null, so whatever code you wrote after that won't actually execute.

If you want to assign the role only after save is successful, you could do so like this:

```
if (!$this->validate()) {
        return null;
    }

    $user = new User();
    $user->username = $this->username;
    $user->email = $this->email;
    $user->role = $this->role;
    $user->setPassword($this->password);
    $user->generateAuthKey();

    if($user->save())
    {

      $myRole = '';

      switch ($user->role) {
          case 0:
              $myRole = 'developer';
              break;
          case 1:
              $myRole = 'project_manager';
              break;
          case 2:
              $myRole = 'customer';
              break;
      }

      $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;
      $role = $auth->getRole($myRole);
      $auth->assign($role, $user->id);

      return true;
    }
    else
      return false;
```

Comment: this has already been mentioned in the answer below, until unless you have another suggestion do not post the answer

Comment: Well, i'm sorry if this bothers you in any way, however, seems to me that when i was still writing my answer, another person sent theirs. That could be because my answer is longer. But still, it also intends to help the OP with the original intention, to save the role after the user creation.

Comment: thats Ok,it just creates a duplicate post, that's all the concern i know it happens sometimes we don't realize the same answer has been posted, no worries.just wanted you to know